# How secure are client-side collections in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How secure are Meteor client-side collections if the insecure package is removed?
If I store auth data used to connect to external resources in client-side collections is it secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[insecure](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/dataandsecurity) is a package that simply allows any user to do almost any kind of operation on the database without validation (thus its name). It should absolutely **never** be used in production, its main use it to quickly prototype an app without having to worry about server validation. Just remove it if you are ready to go further in the development of your application.

You also have to consider the client-side collections to be the dirtiest places you can imagine. Do not trust anything the client sends you or does, validate everything. If you have to store authentication data on the client, make perfectly sure one client can't access the sensible data of another client.

Answer (score 1):

Data stored in client side collections (or even subscriptions) as well as data stored in *Session* is primarily vulnerable to XSS. Presumably your site is https because the accounts package isn't secure without it.

If your client is making authenticated requests to external resources (3rd party sites) then any of your users can figure out what your credentials are by examining your network requests in the browser.